# Load jQuery Functions One by One

Tags: jquery

I have two different `function()` and a hide loading message one.

```
function functionOne(){
   $.get(baseURL + 'xml/', function(one) {
      ...
   });
}

function functionTwo(){
   $.get(baseURL + 'xml/', function(one) {
      ...
   });
}

function hideLoading(){
   $('#loading').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $('#loading').hide();
   });  
}
```

Now, what I am trying to do is to load them one by one. So I want to call `functionTwo` after `functionOne` is loaded and `hideLoading` after `functionTwo` is loaded. This bit of code doesn't work because it hides the loading message before `functionOne` and `functionTwo` is loaded:

```
$('.featuredImage').live('click', function()  {
   functionOne();
   functionTwo();
   hideLoading();
});
```

Somebody can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Ajax is *Asynchronous*, you should call the functions within Ajax's callback function. Also note that `live` method is deprecated, you can use `on` method instead.

```
$(document).on('click', '.featuredImage', functionOne);

function functionOne(){
   $.get(baseURL + 'xml/', function(one) {
      functionTwo();
   });
}

function functionTwo(){
   $.get(baseURL + 'xml/', function(one) {
      hideLoading();
   });
}
```

Comment: Why pass (one) to the function?

Answer (score 2):

Add the next function to the end of the callback

```
function functionOne(){
   $.get(baseURL + 'xml/', function(one) {
      ...
     functionTwo();
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.get()` returns a Promise-compliant jqXHR object.

Returning the jqXHRs from `functionOne()` and `functionTwo()` will allow you to form a `.then()` chain, as follows :

```
function functionOne(){
   return $.get(baseURL + 'xml/');//returns a jqXHR object
}

function functionTwo(){
   return $.get(baseURL + 'xml/');//returns a jqXHR object
}

function hideLoading() {
   $('#loading').fadeOut('slow');  
}

$(document).on('click', '.featuredImage', function() {
   functionOne().then(functionTwo).then(hideLoading);
});
```

Doing it this way keeps `functionOne()` and `functionTwo()` free of assumptions about what should happen next. All the sequencing logic is in the calling function.

Callbacks can be reinserted into the `$.get()` expressions. Providing they do not cause an uncaught error to be thrown, they will not inhibit the sequence.